# C subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int * matrixsum(int *a,int *b,int n,int m)
{
    int *p=NULL,i,j;
    p=malloc(sizeof(int)*n*m);
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            *(p+i*n+j)=*(a+i*n+j)+*(b+i*n+j);
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

My question is about the line `*(p+i*n+j)=*(a+i*n+j)+*(b+i*n+j);`: if I replace it with `p[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];` I get the following error 3 times:

> error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Why? From my knowledge they are the same thing.

My compiler is gcc version 4.6.3.

Comment: You have to say `p[i * n +j]` etc. You only have a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Unrelated: Your index-arithmetic is wrong, `*(p+i*n+j)=*(a+i*n+j)+*(b+i*n+j);` should use `m` instead of `n`.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are absolutely not the same thing. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Note that the "vector" in the error message probably refers to a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions), not to C++ vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same thing at all — which is why the compiler is complaining!  You could write:

```
p[i*n+j] = a[i*n+j] + b[i*n+j];
```

The type of `p` is `int *`; therefore the type of `p[i]` is `int`, and you can't subscript an `int`.  You'd have to be passing a 2D-array of `int`, or an array of pointers to `int`, to be able to use the `p[i][j]` notation. For example, in C99 (using variable-length arrays — and note the reordering of the parameters):

```
int *matrixsum(int n, int m, int a[m][n], int b[m][n])
{
    ...
    p[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    ...
}
```

Or, with some considerable care in the setup, you could use:

```
int *matrixsum(int **a, int **b, int m, int n)
{
    ...
    p[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    ...
}
```

Note that for this latter example, you can't simply write:

```
int a[4][4] = { ... };
int b[4][4] = { ... };
int r = matrixsum(a, b, 4, 4);
```

The memory allocation for the 2D array is quite different from what is required for the `int **` notation.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is simply telling you that you can't de-reference an integer. `p` is only an `int` pointer - similarly for `a`, `b`, and `c`. You can *simulate* `p[i][j]` by doing the tricky pointer arithmetic into your buffer, but you can't de-reference an `int`.

These variables must be `int **` before you can use them as a 2D array, using array subscripts.

Answer (score 1):

> from my knowledge they are the same thing

Yes, you've converted from linear indexing to subscripts correctly, but all 3 of those variables are of the wrong type to apply those subscripts. They need to be of type `int **` for you to be able to do 2-D array indexing.

Comment: An actual 2D array (an array of arrays) is not an `int**`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second form, how can the compiler guess that n is the length of the first dimension of YOUR tab (not his one) ? to compute &t[i][j] == *(t + i * n + j)